# Erro ao fazer chamada REST com o AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, http, cors, angularjs-services

Estou usando o $http do angular para fazer chamadas REST no meu servidor, porém estou com um problema:

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Já tentei várias coisas, mas nada ainda me resolveu, alguém sabe como resolver?

Meu Código:

```
.factory('CotacaoService', ['$http', function($http){
var cotacao = [];
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://192.168.254.8:8084/CotacaoREST/recursos/cotacoes/1/991'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    cotacao = response.data;
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
return cotacao;
```

}]);

Comment: O que você está usando no backend? SpringRest, Jersey? Qual tecnologia?

Comment: Estou usando Jersey

Comment: eu não conheço profundamente o Jersey. No caso do Spring a anotação `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin` resolve. Pesquisando rapidamente eu encontrei algo falando para incluir no header do response o seguinte atributo: `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"`. Veja se este [link](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-add-cors-support-on-the-server-side-in-java-with-jersey/) te ajuda.

Comment: Você está testando no navegador ou em um emulador?

Comment: josivan valeu, vou testar com esse exemplo. andre, estou testando no navegador, no Console do Chrome ou do Firefox me retorna esse erro

Comment: No navegador tem que dar uns comando para habilitar. Estou fazendo um projeto também que só rola no emulador ou no próprio aparelho, no chrome e firefox da o mesmo erro. Tem umas dicas neste link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819060/allow-google-chrome-to-use-xmlhttprequest-to-load-a-url-from-a-local-file

Comment: Fiz os testes aqui com a mudança no jersey e rodando esse comando no chrome e mesmo assim ainda dá o mesmo problema, até estava olhando um tutorial para adicionar três parâmetros no header, e também não funcionou, o estranho é que só acontece com o angular, tenho um projeto em android que consome o webservice e funciona normal, alguém tem alguma ideia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente criar um filtro pra trabalhar com o CORS:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;

@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request,
            ContainerResponseContext response) throws IOException {
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
    }
}
```

**Fonte:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065963/how-to-handle-cors-using-jax-rs-with-jersey

Outra solução seria [essa](http://blog.usul.org/cors-compliant-rest-api-with-jersey-and-containerresponsefilter/).

Comment: Eu tinha feito dessa Forma, porém agora encontrei o problema, essa método resolve no servidor, porém no angular tive que tirar o headers, assim resolvendo meu problema. Obrigado pela ajuda.